# Django wrong request.POST attribute value saved

Tags: python, django, post, request, save

I am experiencing the issue that the code saves request.POST['name'] value to assumptions.Name field in database, but only the last value in the list which is 'B' in this case. How could I make it save both prefixes 'A' and  'B' to database field Name based on respective forms. When I debug I see both 'A' and 'B' with key 'name'.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import modelformset_factory, AssumptionsForm
from .models import Assumptions
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


model_names = ['A', 'B']

def get_assumptions(request):

    AssumptionFormset = modelformset_factory(
    Assumptions, form=AssumptionsForm, extra=5)

    if request.method == 'POST':



        formsets = [AssumptionFormset(request.POST, prefix=thing) for thing in model_names]

        if all([formset.is_valid() for formset in formsets]):

            for formset in formsets:

                for form in formset:

                    assumption_data = form.save(commit=False)
                    assumption_data.Name = request.POST.get('name')
                    assumption_data.save()   



    else:

        formsets = [AssumptionFormset(prefix=thing) for thing in model_names]

    return render(request, 'assumptions.html', {'formsets': formsets})
```

**assumptions.html**

```
<div class="form">
<form action="" method="post">
{% for formset in formsets %} 
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {{ formset.non_form_errors.as_ul }} 
    <h1>{{formset.prefix}}</h1>
    <table id="formset" class="form">
    {% for form in formset.forms %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
    <thead><tr>
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr></thead>
    {% endif %}
    <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            <td>
            {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
            {% if forloop.first %}
            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden }}
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
            {{ field }}
            </td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" id={{formset.prefix}} name='name', value={{formset.prefix}} />
{% endfor %}    
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Assumptions(models.Model):

    Worst = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Base = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Best = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import modelformset_factory, ModelForm
from .models import Assumptions

class AssumptionsForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Assumptions
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['Name']
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I should have used  getlist method and then loop through values.

```
values = request.POST.getlist('name')
```

Cheers.